# Python Fraud Detection Classification Algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science, fraud-prevention

I am working on a credit card fraud detection model and have labeled data containing orders for an online store. The columns I am working with is: Customer Full Name, Shipping Address and Billing Address (city, state, zip, street), Order 
Quantity, Total Cost, and an indicator on whether or not the order was discovered to be fraud.

The problem is the fact that 98%+ of the transactions are not fraudulent- the data set is highly imbalanced. I understand this is a classification problem, however I am unsure where to start with the columns I am working with and the imbalance of the data.

I would appreciate any suggestions of appropriate classification algorithms for this use case and how to deal with the imbalanced data. There are several articles I found when searching for how to solve this, however most are working with a Kaggle dataset that has very different columns (due to security reasons for not allowing the information to be public).

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at imbalanced-learn https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/over_sampling.html. Then you can train a model on the oversampled data.

Comment: Other than the imbalanced data problem, you might need to consider working with better attributes in order to build a stronger fraud detection model. Some of the attributes are user activity, transaction attempts, amount, frequency, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, there are 2 directions for **deal with the imbalanced dataset for anti-fraud cases**:

1. Using `Supervised ML` algorithms for *Fraud prediction*: try to predict a class (fraud/not fraud) of sample
2. Using `Unsupervised ML` algorithms *Anomaly detection*: try to detect unusual customer/merchant behavior or payments activity.

##### Supervised Learning (SL) approach

If you use Supervised ML algorithms (e.g. `Logistic regression`, `Random forest`, `Gradient Boosted Trees`) then you need to apply one or more tricks:

1. **Before** training ML model:

   - Oversampling - *adding* more samples of *the minority class*: `RandomOverSampler`, `SMOTE` (generate synthetic samples) methods in `imblearn` package
   - Undersampling - *removing* some observations of *the majority class*:
     `RandomUnderSampler` method in `imblearn` package
   - Combine Oversampling and Undersampling methods.
2. **While** training ML model:

   - Pass `weights` parameter in the train model method (set higher weights to minor class samples).
3. **After** training ML model:

   - Do not use `accuracy` to estimate the trained model
   - Use `recall`, `precision`, `F1 score`, or/and `AUC PR` (precision-recall curve ) to robust model evaluation.

##### Unsupervised Learning (UL) approach

Unsupervised algorithms don't require the `label` in dataset. That's a reason why there is **no imbalanced classes problem**.

But unlike the SL-based models, UL-based models haven't prediction as output. You need additional actions to interpret output of UL-based models.

The following algorithms most probably will be useful:

1. Anomaly detection methods:

   - `One-class SVM`
   - Isolation forest or `iForest`
   - `Local Outlier Factor`
2. Neural Networks methods:

   - Autoencoder-based networks, e.g. `AE`, `VAE`
   - `DBN` or Deep Belief Network,
   - `GAN` or Generative Adversarial Networks
   - `Self-organized Maps`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read these articles:

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-financial-fraud-using-machine-learning-three-ways-of-winning-the-war-against-imbalanced-a03f8815cce9
2. https://towardsdatascience.com/methods-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-data-5b761be45a18

based on my experience xgboost was very good. But you should have very good features that it can build good trees